# I Have A Member (Or Property Or Method Or Whatever Else), How Do I Get The Class Name It Belongs To (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net

As the title states, how? All members are public with no static members within the class. I have been looking for an answer for a while and have come up with nothing so if this is a duplicate mark it as such and point me to the answer. If more info is required, specify what is needed in the comments and I will provide it.

Comment: Use [`MemberInfo.ReflectedType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have a method has not an exact meaning. Are you inside that method and you want class name? You have a delegate? A MethodInfo?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `MemberInfo`, you can just use the `DeclaringType` property.

```
MemberInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMember("Length")[0];
Type original = mi.DeclaringType; //original is now System.String
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Object class has GetType which returns type of the class from which you invoke this method.
As all classes derive from it, you can call GetType from any instance member.

If you need String then call GetType().ToString(). Below is sample code.

```
    [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CalssNameFromMethod()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine( this.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```